# Is it OK to save Twitter passwords for easy login via the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, social-networking

I'm writing a tool in our web app to allow our users to tweet certain things about our app via the Twitter API. In all the documentation I've seen the Twitter API has you submit the user's username and password via XML or JSON. It would make sense from a usability standpoint to save the username and password for easy reuse (so they don't have to log in everytime they tweet. Although I want to make sure we are allowed to do this before we actually implement the saved username/passwords.

Does anyone know if there are any laws that prevent us from doing this? Is this just what Twitter expects us to do?

Comment: Regarding laws, which country (location) are you in?

Comment: US, but our web app serves world wide

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about law advice, not programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** Basic authentication was removed from the API on August 16, 2010

---

While you can certainly store people's usernames and passwords for use with the Twitter API, this is not the recommended approach.  **Try [Twitter's OAuth Authentication](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ) instead.**

> OAuth is an authentication protocol that allows users to approve applications to act on their behalf without sharing their password.

Twitter will eventually deprecate basic (username/password) authentication in the future.  Mid-2010 is likely.

Comment: Thanks! When I saw OAuth I assumed it was an alternative to logging in via REST. But now it all makes sense that OAuth is preferred and REST login is depreciated. On a related note, I read that REST login limits you to 150 requests/hour by default. I'm assuming if you go with OAuth that you don't have a limit?

Comment: Your rate limits remain even with OAuth, though, you can apply to be white-listed here: http://twitter.com/help/request_whitelisting

More info on rate limits: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting

Comment: Basic authentication will start depreciation in June 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with OAuth, the reason OAuth is beneficial is your site > will no longer need to handle Twitter passwords, store them, protect them, and deal with the legal consequences (Can't link because the work proxy blocks The Twitter wiki lol). Keyword: Legal. Don't store them.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything answering this question one way or the other in the Twitter T&C. In other words, it doesn't seem to be explicitly forbidden, as it is, for example, at Facebook.

But it's clearly undesirable to store other people's usernames and passwords to proxy for them.